# mysql insert into multiple table at once

Tags: php, mysql, insert

the `query` below insert a message note into table:

```
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO msgs VALUES ('', '$user_id', '$username', '$text','$time', )");
```

When inserting into `msgs` table, i want to implement a notification system in which where by when the `$text` variable contain string like `@mention` (insert into notification table with notification type `mention`)

I'v this regular expression to check if `text` variable has `@`:

```
preg_match_all('/(@\w+)/', $msg, $matches); 
foreach ($matches[0] as $username)
```

The notificaion insert query:

```
 mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO notifications VALUES ('', '$trigger_userid', '$trigger_username','$msg_trigger_recvr_id', '$recipient_uname', '$action', '$status', '$time', now() ) ");
```

Explanation:

1st empty `' '` contains the id column that is auto incremented.

`$trigger_userid` is the `id` of the user that making the mention

`$trigger_username` is the `username` of the user that making the mention

`$msg_trigger_recvr_id` i want this to be the `id` of that particular message note in the msg table.

`$recipient_uname` this will be the `@mention` from the regular expression. In case `$text` contain multiple mentions (`@mention1` and `@mention2`), i want to insert each in new row

`$action` is mention and `$staus` is `unread` by default.

The problem is i cannot insert all values of  foreach ,  it inserts only the last `mention` in a case where there is multiple `mentions`, i'll like to the values in new rows.

Pls, kindly help.

Comment: I don't see a question or an explanation of what doesn't work at the moment. Please edit the question to clearly state what you need help with

Comment: For auto_increment you no need to give `' '` like this..that will insert automatically

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen question has been updated, thanks.

Comment: @chris85 thanks, it was a mistake. i'v updated the question to state the problem.

Comment: See LAST_INSERT_ID (and/or its companion function in PHP)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not permit insertion into multiple tables using a single INSERT statement, if that is what you need clarity upon. Further, please state what does not work with the above code.

Comment: Can you upload this part of the code? Also what I can figure out from this it should be :-
foreach ($matches as $username)
as you need to pass in the array variable and not a particular array index.
I can better say after looking at this part of the code but this may be one of the problems.